# PHP not printing html form element using its ID attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html

I can't PHP echo a label element with an ID attribute from an HTML form I'm wanting to use the ID attribute as I'd have to change the JS code so that I can use the name attribute instead

I've tried using different HTML elements Changing code around

***a.html***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }

            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var subA;
            var subB;
            var subC;

            function updateAll() {
                var a = 10;
                var b = 15;
                var c = 20;

                var qtyA = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantityA').value);
                var qtyB = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantityB').value);
                var qtyC = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantityC').value);
                var qtyTotal = qtyA + qtyB + qtyC;

                document.getElementById('quantityTotal').innerHTML = qtyTotal;

                var subA = parseInt(a * qtyA);
                var subB = parseInt(b * qtyB);
                var subC = parseInt(c * qtyC);

                document.getElementById('subtotalA').innerHTML = parseInt(a * qtyA);
                document.getElementById('subtotalB').innerHTML = parseInt(b * qtyB);
                document.getElementById('subtotalC').innerHTML = parseInt(c * qtyC);

                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = parseInt(subA + subB + subC);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="b.php" method="POST">
            <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Products</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product A</td>
                    <td>$10</td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="quantityA" name="quantityA" onkeyup="updateAll();" value=0 min="1" max="50"></td>
                    <td><label id="subtotalA" name="subtotalA"></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product B</td>
                    <td>$15</td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="quantityB" name="quantityB" onkeyup="updateAll();" value=0 min="1" max="50"></td>
                    <td><label id="subtotalB" name="subtotalB"></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product A</td>
                    <td>$20</td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="quantityC" name="quantityC" onkeyup="updateAll();" value=0 min="1" max="50"></td>
                    <td><label id="subtotalC" name="subtotalC"></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td><label id="quantityTotal" name="quantityTotal"></label></td>  
                    <td><label id="total" name="total"></label></td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </body>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

***b.php***

```
<?php 
    // Variables
    $qtyA = $_POST['quantityA'];
    $qtyB = $_POST['quantityB'];
    $qtyC = $_POST['quantityC'];
    $subA = $_POST['subtotalA'];
    $subB = $_POST['subtotalB'];
    $subC = $_POST['subtotalC'];
    $qtyTotal = $_POST['quantityTotal'];
    $total = $_POST['total'];
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Products</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ProductA</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td><?php echo $qtyA ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $subA ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ProductB</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td><?php echo $qtyB ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $subB ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ProductA</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td><?php echo $qtyC ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $subC ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <th>Total</th>
                <td><?php echo $qtyTotal ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $total ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </body>
</html>
```

I was expecting PHP to echo the html form element using ID just like it can with name attribute

Comment: `<label>`'s do not submit in a form

Comment: I've tried other alternatives before label, do you know what other element to use that I can retrieve its data through ID

Comment: [Elements that are considered form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Elements_that_are_considered_form_controls)

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, [PHP not echoing ID of HTML form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477875/php-not-echoing-id-of-html-form-element)

Comment: That you _have to_ use the name attribute, was already explained to you when you asked this question the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work like that. With post or get only the name attribute is sent over to the php

Comment: Ahh okay, I thought I read somewhere on a few pages online that id attribute can be used.